# VPN encryption per device

Tags: vpn

When you use the same VPN (for example NordVPN) with same username and password on several devices, if one device is compromised/hacked, can it be used to decrypt the traffic of the other device using the same VPN? Or does it weaken the encryption of the same device in any way?

I guess it doesn't, since the encryption keys are different for each device I think, but I wanted to have your advice.

Comment: If it were possible, then every VPN customer would be vulnerable to anyone else who used the same service and knows how to decrypt that service's encryption.

Answer (score 2):

No, such a breach should not happen as any respectable VPN service will generate separate keys for each client.

Your data is encrypted, so even if someone that compromised the network does look at what you’re sending, they only see encrypted information and not raw data.

Comment: ok, yes, thanks for your reply. Just to clarify though: are the keys separate for each device or only for each client (or do you mean client as a client application?) ? Because I would use the same username and password on both devices. I edited the post just now to precise that.